# Oracle sql - convert string to date

Tags: sql, oracle

i am having problems with converting a varchar(yyyymmdd) to date(yyyymmdd).

i have a procedure with a parameter (pdate varchar2, yyyymmdd format) which needed to be converted to date type in yyyymmdd format as well. 
so far i tried.

```
vdate date;

 vdate := (to_date(SUBSTR(pdate,1,4)+SUBSTR(pdate,5,2)+SUBSTR(pdate,7,2), 'yyyymmdd'));
```

this threw a error of ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of a pdate that is failing?  change `+` to `||`  Consider: `SELECT (SUBSTR('20170101',1,4)||SUBSTR('20170101',5,2)||SUBSTR('20170101',7,2))
     , to_date(SUBSTR('20170101',1,4)||SUBSTR('20170101',5,2)||SUBSTR('20170101',7,2),'YYYYMMDD')
     , To_date('20170101','YYYYDDMM') from dual;`

Comment: you just need `to_date(pdate, 'yyyymmdd')`, assuming that your pdate contains the full set of information. In fact, I'm pretty sure you can get rid of your procedure and just use the `to_date()` function!

Comment: The reason your attempt is failing, as has been pointed out, is that concatenation is done with `||` in Oracle, not with `+`. What you are doing is that you are extracting the year, month and date, as strings (four digits, two digits, two digits). Then you *add* them. Behind the scenes, Oracle converts them to `NUMBER` and adds them. Then you apply `to_date()` which takes a `varchar2` input, so Oracle - again behind the scenes - converts the result of the addition to a four-character string. Which is not long enough to become a date (and it would be a wrong one anyway!)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a to_date

```
select to_date(MyDate, 'yyyymmdd')
from mytable
```

Test with:

```
select to_date('20170831','yyyymmdd')
from dual
```

Also, to concatenate in Oracle, use a double pipe `||`

```
select 'Chicken'||'Food'
from dual
```

Answer (score 2):

If pdate has other characters after yyyymmdd, and yyyymmdd is in the beginning of the whole text, you can just use

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(pdate,1,8), 'yyyymmdd')
  FROM yourtable;
```

Example

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR('20170831 10:30am',1,8), 'yyyymmdd')
  FROM dual;
```

Otherwise, you can directly use TO_DATE() as suggested by most that replied

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as far as PL/SQL oracle syntax is concerned. Kudos.